# How do I preview a file in safari on iPad?

Tags: javascript, ipad, angularjs, safari

I have a web service which returns a file, I've put the web service url in  tag, so it becomes:
`<a href="webserviceurl/someurl"/>`, when I click the link and try to open this in safari on iPad, it simply gives me "safari cannot download this file". When I open this link in desktop and see the response document, the header of the file is like below:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test.doc"
Content-Type: application/x-msdownload
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Mon, 10 Jun 2013 02:26:50 GMT
```

I guess it's "Content-Disposition" which makes this happen, because I tried a url which has a direct link to the file like `<a href="/somefile.doc"/>` it previews the file perfectly on iPad.

I'm not able to change the web service, I can only modify javascript code, and our application is built on angularJS, is there any solution I can do to preview the file on iPad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as im aware, ios safari does not support file downloading, which when you have the attachment in content-disposition, is what the browser is instructed to do.

Therefore, the only way to solve this would be to use a proxy server that you can control, where your javascript app talks to your proxy server, your proxy server gets the file for your app, then sends it to your app without the offending headers so the ipad will open it for preview.

Simple php proxy:

```
//-- Get the file url from request url 
//-- Should probably do some security checks on this but this is a simple example
$file = $_GET['file'];

//-- this essentially downloads the file, once again this is a simple example, you may want to use curl and write the file to /tmp otherwise large files will fail or crash your server (also curl is more reliable)
$file_contents = file_get_contents($file);

//-- we now have the file, so we set our custom headers (you will have to decide on this)
header('Content-Type: application/whatever');

//-- dump out the contents, since we have it in memory, we can echo the variable
//-- of writing to file via curl, you would read the file out to the browser at x bytes at a time until completed 
echo $file_contents;
```

Note: the above really is very insecure, its just there to show how a simple proxy works. you need to think about security first and foremost. If the files will always be on a specific 3rd party host, then hard-code the domain and only allow a file path to be given e.c.t.

Comment: thanks for your response and it's certainly true, BTW, I managed to use angularJS's interceptor concept to get the response dom which has the header and body, is there any way to open the file with these?

Comment: BTW, is there any proxy server technology you can recommend?

Comment: I've never really used angularJS so i can't say regarding the interceptor thing. Even with the data, i can't think of a way to make the iPad open it, as you need the safari browser to read the response headers, to detect the file and open it as a preview. Unless you can sort of forge a response in JS and put the data into the body of the response, it's of no use (which i think would be impossible as header's are read prior to client side JS being invoked). Regarding a php proxy script, you can build one yourself , see my main post above in 5 mins

Comment: @hiphop101 ok i've added something very simple, hopefully you understand PHP enough, but its relatively simple, you download the file on your php server, set your custom headers compatible with ipad, then dump the file back out. There's security and memory issues to think about, but hopefully you can either work those out, or google around for something like "php download script" which is half of what the script does

Comment: How can i achieve preview using Javascript with C# API?